# What would be a word for the science of buildings?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to come up with a word for the science and study of buildings and of their inhabitants. This would include, but not be restricted to, the study of building physics, energy, indoor environmental quality, ergonomics, etc. The goal is to come up with a two-word phrase for the use of computers in that field, i.e. *Computational XXXology* or something similar.

We already have *Building Science* or *Building Physics* but I find that *Computational Building Science* becomes clumsy.

I've been looking up different synonyms for buildings and their greek translation:

- building: ktirio
- house: spiti
- residence: katokoia
- construction: oikodomue

And I suppose this would yield ktiriology, spitiology, katokoiology, or oikodumology. None of which makes for a particularly memorable word.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think Architecture covers everything you listed.  Suggestion:  Look at the course offerings of the architecture programs at several leading schools (e.g., MIT, Yale).

Comment: @ab2 It's close, but I wouldn't say that Architecture is about the scientific study of buildings.

Comment: Taking ab2's suggesting, there seem to be several universities which offer programs in what they call "Building Science".   Slightly anticlimactic...

Comment: @GrumbleSnatch That would be two words ;-)

Comment: @lindelof Hence the comment, and not an answer :P

Comment: [Building Science on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building_science). Why do you need it to be single word, knowing it will sound strange to people? I'm curious.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Comment: @HotLicks Good point. I've edited the question to clarify my goal.

Comment: If you do use a Greek root, I would recommend using a classical one with the classical transliteration, rather than a modern one. It's more traditional, and it looks less out-of-place in an English word. (That's just my opinion.)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, people who do these sorts of things have the title:

> Civil engineer - Architectural and Interior design

I have heard the phrase Building Science thrown around too:
http://archdesign.vt.edu/architecture-design/building_science.php

This page yields another interesting phrase, "Building Information Modeling".

In your situation, instead of Computational Building Science, you could instead use Building Information Sciences or BIS as an acronym.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions: the first is ***Computational Architecture***.

When I google **computational architecture**, I come up with many entries, including one from the [MIT Design and Computation Group](https://architecture.mit.edu/discipline/computation) (MIT Department of Architecture.)

> Our work is informed simultaneously by architectural practice as well
>   as a variety of other disciplinary perspectives including mathematics,
>   computer science, cognitive science, philosophy, anthropology, STS
>   (Science, Technology, and Society), media studies, and art......... [Students] are expected to acquire both the technical skills and the theoretical and conceptual foundations to rethink and challenge the limits of current design processes and practices.

The same reference mentions

> construction processes and technologies

I make the second suggestion only because the OP was thinking along Greek-root lines. The OP's research turned up several possibilities; the only one whose root I recognized was *oikodomue* (construction).

This suggests *computational oikosology or computational weikology*

Oikos "house, dwelling place, habitation", is the root for economics and ecology. [Etomoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=e&p=2&allowed_in_frame=0).  Oikos comes from the Indo European root weik (house), which gives rise to village through the Latin vicus (Mario Pei, *The Families of Words*)  See also *villa* on [Etomoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=v&p=9&allowed_in_frame=0) for other roots you could co-opt.